# Can I tell a function explicitly to not accept pointers to non-heap variables?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++, warnings

I've noticed that g++ is smart enough to identify when a function is returning a pointer to a temporary/local variable, e.g.

```
int *foobar()
{
      int a;
      return &a;
}
```

Will result in:

```
 warning: address of local variable ‘a’ returned
```

Is there a way that I can define a function prototype to only accept pointers that the compiler can tell are not temporary.  So lets say I have a function

```
 barfoo(int *a_int);
```

Is there a way I can tell g++ to complain if someone passes a pointer to a local/temporary object into it?  This would prohibit people from calling barfoo with invalid pointers and potentially save debugging some annoying issues.

Example:

```
   void barfoo(int *a)
   {
        cerr << a << endl;
   };

   void foobar()
   {
        int a;
        barfoo(&a);
   }
```

I would like the compiler to complain about the `barfoo(&a)'.

Comment: You can't take te address of a temporary, so this is a non issue.

Comment: There are instances where passing a pointer to a local variable is valid.  Many date back to the C language where one way to pass variables is by pointers.

Comment: @Dennis Zikefoose:  What about this: `void f(void) { int a = 0; int * pa = &a; *pa = 25; return;}`.  It takes the address of a temporary.

Comment: So you want to allow only pointers to global variables? Everything else is "temporary" in the sense that it may stop being valid at some future time, either because it goes out of scope or because somebody explicitly frees it.

Comment: @Thomas, "temporary" is a technical term in C++; it refers to unknown intermediate objects produced by expressions and not (yet) assigned to a named local variable. They are distinct from declared locals. (However, clearly the OP was not using that specialized meaning).

Comment: @Dennis, is there something that (at compile time) prevents a class from having a `const` member function that returns its own this pointer, and then calling that function on a temporary?

Comment: Yes, I am aware that there are very valid use-cases for doing this, but I know in this case that it is not.  I.e. after the pointer is passed to the function it now ``owns'' it:  It is responsible for freeing it.

Comment: @Henning Quite right, I stand corrected.  I should have been more specific to refer to locals and temporaries and anything that will not persist if left alone ;)

Comment: @Henning: it would be more approprriate to say you can't apply the address-of operator to a temporary. The object has an address, so your hypothetical is allowed.

Comment: @Dennis -- playing devil's advocate here :-) -- isn't that just a matter of overloading `operator&`? Of course one could argue that then the overload isn't "the address-of operator" but merely something homonymous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to get the compiler to enforce it, but you can detect some instances earlier by using malloc_size.

```
void someFunc(int * mustBeHeap) {
   assert(0!=malloc_size(mustBeHeap));
   //do stuff
}
```

Unfortunately you will get false positives from code like this:

```
void someOtherFunc() {
    int * myInts=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*20);
    someFunc(&(myInts[3]));
}
```

It won't work too well with anything allocated with new, boost::pool, etc.  In fact, you will get false positives from just about everything.

Also, malloc_size is non-standard.

**Edit:**

After looking at one of your comments above about taking ownership, it looks like some of the things I described as false positives are in fact situations you also want to detect since you intended to free the memory from the pointer.

Comment: Getting closer, thanks for the input, the only issue is that assert() is a runtime check I believe.

Comment: @thehelix Yes it is, but this way you can detect the error when the function is called instead of the variable goes out of scope and you start overwriting part of the stack.

Comment: Good point!  `malloc_size()` is macos only?  Not finding anything about it for linux.

Comment: @thehelix I didn't realize that, I thought it was in all versions of gcc.  Someone here http://fixunix.com/unix/84654-malloc_size.html says mallinfo might be available.  It's msize on Windows.

Comment: `malloc_usable_size()` - http://fuse4bsd.creo.hu/localcgi/man-cgi.cgi?malloc+3 is close to what we want I think, except it segvs on non-heap variables for me.  If that was gaurunteed and portable though that'd still be better than non-deterministic bugs.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

You could instruct the compiler to flag that warning as an error. But beware of defining your problem incorrectly. A function that accepts a pointer to a local is valid use case:

```
int a;
...
do_something (&a);
printf ("%d\n", a);
```

Comment: The issue is the compiler doesn't complain if I do what I am describing.  Lemme update the original post with an example.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can be totally useful to do what you want to avoid there. GCC/G++ cannot guess that the function taking the reference/pointer will store it somewhere to later reuse, when the original caller of the function has already left the call-stack.

Comment: Yes it _can_ be, but it is not in my case.  Hence I'd like to tell the compiler about it so it can catch people doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell gcc to treat warnings as errors with `-Werror` option. Or make the specified warning as error `-Werror=`. [3.8 Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get a compiler set up to treat warnings as errors (as you should anyway!), but I don't believe there's a way to do what you're asking aside from that.

Answer (score 0):

Never, ever, use raw pointers in C++ without a good reason. In this case, since you plan on taking ownership of the pointer, accept an object that reflects that. Either `auto_ptr` \ `unique_ptr`, if you want sole ownership, or `shared_ptr` otherwise. If you aren't taking ownership, accept a (possibly const) reference.

Comment: Interesting comments.. are those rules derived from a desire for safety, performance, understanding or what?  Unique_ptr will work to enforce ownership, but will not achieve what I am asking I don't think?

Comment: @thehelix: safety, and clarity of imtent. By asking for a `unique_ptr`, you explicitly tell the user of your function "I plan on calling delete on this object" so if they pass non-heap memory that's on them.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ you could write a "guaranteed heap pointer" template class that contains a single real pointer inside but has tightly restricted constructors such that the only way to create one was by `new`. Overload enough operators, and you could have it behave almost like a naked pointer, except that it will have no conversion 
*from* such a pointer.

(I have my doubts about whether that will be worth the trouble, though).